# Dynamic rest URL

Tags: angular, typescript

Can I change the url from an external function?

In case I need to pull different information from different db

```
export const environment = {
      production: false,
      firebase: {
       //firebase api {..}
      },
      restUrl: 'http://localhost:1337/'
    };
```

Comment: what is the extension of your file?

Comment: file is environment.ts, ty

Comment: then you can create a function and runned when you load the file, and create the url dynamically